# Stand-alone web application vs Api-driven application

Tags: architecture, asp.net-web-api2, restful-architecture

Which one of the two is better? Is it better to have a Web API and an application not connected to it or have a Web API that supplies the application with data?
I see that there might be delays when getting the data from the API instead of directly from the database, but using the API as main source of data for all clients change there will affect everything. Can you tell me pros and cons of each design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have any type of architecture. e.g. Asp.net web api, Asp.net MVC, Asp.net web pages, Asp.net MVC-API, Asp.net webpage-api and so on.

First of all if you target any specific or combined architecture, it has its own pros and cons.It is also very important to understand the scope and requirement of your project. Keep in mind by any way or architecture you'd achieve the goals but how faster and smoothly you can do it, matters a lot.

**ASP.NET WEB API** :

Nowadays APIs are very powerful and mainly deal with the data only. It has nothing to do with views.

Web Apis returns data in required format and later you can process that data. e.g. Facebook api. Once you use facebook api, if request is authenticated or valid, it returns valid user data which you would use in your application.

Apis are developed under specific platform but can be used by any platform once made.For example asp.net web api. Let's say I have created one web api which returns list of customers. Now this api can be used by multiple platforms like android, php, ios etc.

Testing is not tough compare to specific tightly couple architecture like asp.net webforms.

So ultimately Apis are data-driven architecture.

**Stand-alone application**:

Consider asp.net mvc. View are tightly coupled with the controllers. 
Once code is written you can not use them through other platforms.

Testing is not easy compare to apis.

Yet answer is not given in detail but hopefully it will clear your few doubts immediately.